# Docker: kafka confluent go client error

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to use apache kafka with go, things look good when i execute the project with go run but when i use  docker build i get error....

```
# pkg-config --cflags rdkafka
Package rdkafka was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `rdkafka.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'rdkafka' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

I installed librdkafka from https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go

```
 git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git
 cd librdkafka
 ./configure --prefix /usr
 make
 sudo make install
```

I tried

1. PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
2. source ~/.bashrc

but not luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, where have you added rdkafka?

Comment: It looks like the `librdkafka` isn't installed? That is what the error message is indicating, anyway. If you have installed it, then please [edit] the question to detail how you've installed it. Also see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/61) btw

Comment: Hello Martin, It is installed. Everthing works fine with go run. The problem is with docker build. Also i have tried the link you suggested but no help.

Comment: Hello Cricket,  I am using RUN go get ./   in dockerfile.

Comment: You installed it on the host system only, and not inside the Docker container?

Comment: i assume RUN go get ./   should take care of it.  Normally i dont install any github packages inside docker container.Can you please direct me as to how this can eb acheved.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should include librdkafka.dll, msvcr120.dll and zlib.dll in your project root. At least this is what i should do to get this work on Windows. Not sure about Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This below line inside the Dockerfile worked for me as this sets the environmental variable and this will persist when a container is run from the resulting image.

ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH ${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/usr/lib/pkgconfig/